# Creating a Firestore document with a reference in cloud functions on update from updated item

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this function that listens to updates on `Firestore Document` via `functions.firestore.document().onUpdate()`.

Here is a snippet of how I'd like to approach it:

```
exports.createItem = functions.firestore
  .document('list/{itemId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const ref = REFERENCE_TO_DOCUMENT_CHANGED; // how to do this?
    const changedData = change.after.data();
    const changedValueId = changedData.id;
    const create = admin.firestore().doc(`newlist/${changedValueId}`);
    create.set({
      item: ref,
      ...changedData
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Cloud Functions documentation on Firestore `onUpdate` trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) it seems that the updated document is available in `change.after`. The `DocumentReference` for that document is thus available as `change.after.ref` (or `change.before.ref`, since `change.before` and `change.after` refer to different snapshots of the same document).